# Loading assemblies from memory (embedded Mono runtime)

Tags: c, mono, embed, scriptengine

I want to load mono assemblies from **memory**. So instead of using the usual mono_domain_assembly_open I use **mono_image_open_from_data**. The returned image and assembly are OK and the status is **MONO_IMAGE_OK**.

```
        m_valid = true;

        mono_set_dirs(assembliesDir.c_str(), configDir.c_str());

        MonoImageOpenStatus status = MONO_IMAGE_ERROR_ERRNO;

        m_image = mono_image_open_from_data(data, size, 1, &status);

        if(status != MONO_IMAGE_OK || m_image == NULL) {
            m_valid = false;

            return;
        }

        m_assembly = mono_assembly_load_from( m_image, assembliesName.c_str(), &status);

        if(status != MONO_IMAGE_OK || m_assembly == NULL) {
            m_valid = false;

            return;
        }
```

However when I try to get a class from the assembly using :

```
MonoClass *my_class = mono_class_from_name (m_image, name_space.c_str(), name.c_str());
```

I get **my_class == NULL**. When I use the usual **mono_image_open_from_data** Mono returns a valid class instance.
I suspect that the method doesn't load correctly all the references. Do you have any suggestions or workarounds ?

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: We tried many things but nothing worked, because when you load an assembly from memory it doesn't automatically load its dependencies ...

Comment: One way how you could achieve this is by calling Assembly.Load from mono